# How do you use XPath to select values based between a range of a specific attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xml node that is repeated per  country. Here is an example one:

```
<country name="Afghanistan" population="22664136" area="647500">
```

I want to apply a template on a specific set range of data based on the value of the attribute "population". Specifically I want to pull back all that are larger than 9 million (9000000) and smaller than 10 million (10000000).

Im not terribly comfortable yet with XSLT and XPath. Here is what I expected to work:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="country[@population > '9000000' and population < '10000000']"/>
```

However this throws an error based on the '<' character in the value range.

I did a bit of google-fu and I couldnt find anything to shed some light on what I should be doing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since XSLT is a XML syntax, If you use > and <, the interpreter will understand the start or end of tag.

use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of < and >,

so your xpath would become 
`<xsl:apply-templates select="country[@population &gt; '9000000' and @population &lt; '10000000']"/>`

Comment: Even though JLRishe provided the same answer I ticked this one because it is more semantic (I think?) Thanks to you both!

Comment: @Aleski You are free to accept any answer you wish. However, you should have learned from JLRishe's answer that (1) the `>` character does not need to be escaped; and (2) numbers do not need to be quoted. Escaping the `>` character is benign (I think), however quoting the numbers converts them to strings - and the processor must convert them back to numbers before comparing them. So this is not "more semantic", but rather "more CPU-intensive".

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `<` character because XSLT is XML, and use a `@` before `population` both times.

And there's no need for quotes around the numbers:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="country[@population > 9000000 and 
                                     @population &lt; 10000000]" />
```

Comment: Hah. How odd. Like I said I'm not too familiar with XSL or XPath. I can see this catching me up more than once. Any reason why you have to do that?

Comment: [XML well-formedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document): _key syntax rules provided in the specification include: None of the special syntax characters such as "<" and "&" appear except when performing their markup-delineation roles._ Escaping `>` is optional and that is why I usually choose not to do so.